# Почему то уходит в минус

Tags: php

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста я учу php и не могу решить достаточно легкую задачу

Называется "Айфон в кредит" я типа беру айфон в кредит,

оплачиваю все вроде нормально но вот в конце банк остается должен мне хотя так не должно я должен оплатить остаток и все.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$creditBalance = 40000; /* Долг анона перед банком */
$percent = 1.03; /* Банк начисляет 3% в месяц от суммы */
$servicePayment = 1000; /* А также 1000 рублей в месяц комиссии за обслуживание счета */
$monthlyPayment = 5000; /* Анон платит 5000 р в месяц, это все, что ему дает мама на завтраки */
$paymentTotal = 0; /* Сколько всего отдал банку анон */



/* Посчитаем расходы 20 раз на 20 месяцев вперед */
for ($month = 1; $month <= 20; $month ++) {

    $creditBalance = ( $creditBalance * $percent ) + $servicePayment;  // 4000 * 1.03 = 


    if($creditBalance <= $monthlyPayment){

        $creditBalance = $creditBalance - $monthlyPayment;
        $paymentTotal = $paymentTotal + $monthlyPayment;

    } else{
        $creditBalance = $creditBalance - $monthlyPayment;
        $paymentTotal = $paymentTotal + $monthlyPayment;
    }




    echo "{$month} месяц спустя: долг = {$creditBalance} руб, выплачено всего {$paymentTotal} руб. \n";


    if ($creditBalance <= 0){
        echo "Ура я закончил\n\n";
        break;
    }

}
```

вот ссылка http://ideone.com/m8yga9

Comment: Посмотрите на условие `if($creditBalance <= $monthlyPayment)`: у вас одинаковые ветви. Может быть, нужно сделать что-то другое?

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста целый день мучаюсь

Comment: Просто руководствуясь «жизненной» логикой: если сумма, которую нужно заплатить (переменная `$creditBalance`) меньше, чем сумма денег, которая есть у анона в наличии (переменная `$monthlyPayment`) , то нужно ли анону отдавать все деньги банку? Или можно не все, а столько, сколько нужно?

Comment: @Imieee нужно что бы получилось так
Анон должен оплатить за 13 месяц ровно остаток и все а сейчас банк остается должным анону это ведь не правильно, помогите пожалуйста написать так что бы я оплатить остаток а банк не оставался должен мне

Comment: http://ideone.com/IiMrSS

Comment: @Imieee спасибо огромное, только если честно я не понял как мы можем отнять долг с долга =) Анон же должен заплатить долг а сейчас как будто мы сделали так был долг и долг оплатил долг что ли?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54332/discussion-between-im-ieee-and--).

Answer (score 0):

```
$credit = 40000;
$persent = 1.03;
$servicePayment = 1000;
$monthlyPayment = 5000;

$total = 0;
$months = 0;

while ( $credit >0 ){
    $credit = ($credit * $persent) + $servicePayment;

    if ($monthlyPayment < $credit) {
        $credit -= $monthlyPayment;
        $total  += $monthlyPayment;
    }
    else {  # последняя выплата
        $total += $credit;
        $credit = 0;
    }
    $months++;
    printf ("Loan after $months months is %.02f RUR (%.02f RUR already payed)\n", $credit, $total);
}
```

Результат:

```
Loan after 1 mounths is 37200.00 RUR (5000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 2 mounths is 34316.00 RUR (10000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 3 mounths is 31345.48 RUR (15000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 4 mounths is 28285.84 RUR (20000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 5 mounths is 25134.42 RUR (25000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 6 mounths is 21888.45 RUR (30000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 7 mounths is 18545.11 RUR (35000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 8 mounths is 15101.46 RUR (40000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 9 mounths is 11554.50 RUR (45000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 10 mounths is 7901.14 RUR (50000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 11 mounths is 4138.17 RUR (55000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 12 mounths is 262.32 RUR (60000.00 RUR already payed)
Loan after 13 mounths is 0.00 RUR (61270.19 RUR already payed)
```